# How to simplify a Parsec rule which modifies user state

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec

In learning Parsec, I've found that somewhat verbose rules like

```
type PhonemeClassMap = Map Char String
type ContextElement = Parser String

phonemeContext :: Parsec String PhonemeClassMap ContextElement
phonemeContext = do
    c <- lower
    return $ char c
```

can be simplified by lifting functions like `char` into the `Parsec` / `ParsecT` monad.

```
phonemeContext :: Parsec String PhonemeClassMap ContextElement
phonemeContext = liftM char lower
```

Now I'm trying to simplify a rule which modifies the user state:

```
import Data.Map (insert)

phonemeClassDefinition :: Parsec String PhonemeClassMap ()
phonemeClassDefinition = do
    upperChar <- upper
    lowerChars <- char ':' >> spaces >> many1 lower
    modifyState (insert upperChar lowerChars)
```

I can easily lift `insert :: Char -> String -> PhonemeClassMap -> PhonemeClassMap` to make the following improvement:

```
phonemeClassDefinition = do
    f <- liftM2 insert upper (char ':' >> spaces >> many1 lower)
    modifyState f
```

Is there any way to state these two expressions as one? The same lifting technique does not work for `modifyState :: Monad m -> (u -> u) -> ParsecT s u m ()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you are looking for monadic bind `>>= :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` which allows you to apply a function that takes a pure `a` and returns a monadic action to a monadic `a` (i.e. apply the function "through" the monad). This function is actually an integral part of the monadic type class, and is what the `<-` in `do` notation desugars to under the hood.

(Side note, unlike `liftM2`, `liftM3`..., there doesn't appear to be predefined `bindM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c` (or `bindM3` etc) for convenience. ([Hoogle draws a blank](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+m+c%29+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+b+-%3E+m+c).))

Also, Parsec parsers often benefit (stylistically and otherwise) from using its Applicative and Functor instances, not just its Monad one, specifically `<$>` (alias of `fmap`/`liftM`) and the various (semi-)equivalents of monadic `ap` & `>>`: [`<*>`, `<*` & `*>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--42--62-).

```
phonemeContext = char <$> lower

phonemeClassDefinition = (insert <$> upper <*> (char ':' *> spaces *> many1 lower)) >>= modifyState
```

(Note that @melpomene's `=<<` is just `flip (>>=)`, i.e. with the arguments swapped.)

Answer (score 2):

```
modifyState =<< liftM2 insert upper (char ':' >> spaces >> many1 lower)
```